# A running sum for daily data that resets when month turns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a 2 column table (tibble), made up of a date object and a numeric variable. There is maximum one entry per day but not every day has an entry (ie date is a natural primary key). I am attempting to do a running sum of the numeric column along with dates but with the running sum resetting when the month turns (the data is sorted by ascending date). I have replicated what I want to get as a result below.

```
Date         score  monthly.running.sum
10/2/2019       7       7
10/9/2019       6       13
10/16/2019      12      25
10/23/2019      2       27
10/30/2019      13      40
11/6/2019       2       2
11/13/2019      4       6
11/20/2019      15      21
11/27/2019      16      37
12/4/2019       4       4
12/11/2019      24      28
12/18/2019      28      56
12/25/2019      8       64
1/1/2020        1       1
1/8/2020        15      16
1/15/2020       9       25
1/22/2020       8       33
```

It looks like the package "runner" is possibly suited to this but I don't really understand how to instruct it. I know I could use a `join` operation plus a `group_by` using `dplyr` to do this, but the data set is very very large and doing so would be wildly inefficient. i could also manually iterate through the list with a loop, but that also seems inelegant. last option i can think of is selecting out a unique vector of `yearmon` objects and then cutting the original list into many shorter lists and running a plain `cumsum` on it, but that also feels unoptimal. I am sure this is not the first time someone has to do this, and given how many tools there is in the `tidyverse` to do things, I think I just need help finding the right one. The reason I am looking for a tool instead of using one of the methods I described above (which would take less time than writing this post) is because this code needs to be very very readable by an audience that is less comfortable with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lubridate`, you can extract month and year values from the date, group_by those values and them perform the cumulative sum as follow:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Month = month(mdy(Date)),
              Year = year(mdy(Date))) %>%
  group_by(Month, Year) %>%
  mutate(SUM = cumsum(score))

# A tibble: 17 x 6
# Groups:   Month, Year [4]
   Date       score monthly.running.sum Month  Year   SUM
   <chr>      <int>               <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 10/2/2019      7                   7    10  2019     7
 2 10/9/2019      6                  13    10  2019    13
 3 10/16/2019    12                  25    10  2019    25
 4 10/23/2019     2                  27    10  2019    27
 5 10/30/2019    13                  40    10  2019    40
 6 11/6/2019      2                   2    11  2019     2
 7 11/13/2019     4                   6    11  2019     6
 8 11/20/2019    15                  21    11  2019    21
 9 11/27/2019    16                  37    11  2019    37
10 12/4/2019      4                   4    12  2019     4
11 12/11/2019    24                  28    12  2019    28
12 12/18/2019    28                  56    12  2019    56
13 12/25/2019     8                  64    12  2019    64
14 1/1/2020       1                   1     1  2020     1
15 1/8/2020      15                  16     1  2020    16
16 1/15/2020      9                  25     1  2020    25
17 1/22/2020      8                  33     1  2020    33
```

An alternative will be to use `floor_date` function in order ot convert each date as the first day of each month and the calculate the cumulative sum:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Floor = floor_date(mdy(Date), unit = "month")) %>%
  group_by(Floor) %>%
  mutate(SUM = cumsum(score))

# A tibble: 17 x 5
# Groups:   Floor [4]
   Date       score monthly.running.sum Floor        SUM
   <chr>      <int>               <int> <date>     <int>
 1 10/2/2019      7                   7 2019-10-01     7
 2 10/9/2019      6                  13 2019-10-01    13
 3 10/16/2019    12                  25 2019-10-01    25
 4 10/23/2019     2                  27 2019-10-01    27
 5 10/30/2019    13                  40 2019-10-01    40
 6 11/6/2019      2                   2 2019-11-01     2
 7 11/13/2019     4                   6 2019-11-01     6
 8 11/20/2019    15                  21 2019-11-01    21
 9 11/27/2019    16                  37 2019-11-01    37
10 12/4/2019      4                   4 2019-12-01     4
11 12/11/2019    24                  28 2019-12-01    28
12 12/18/2019    28                  56 2019-12-01    56
13 12/25/2019     8                  64 2019-12-01    64
14 1/1/2020       1                   1 2020-01-01     1
15 1/8/2020      15                  16 2020-01-01    16
16 1/15/2020      9                  25 2020-01-01    25
17 1/22/2020      8                  33 2020-01-01    33
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that this was possible. I (incorrectly) imagined that the ```group_by``` operation would collapse the data by the group dimension and i would lose the day dimension (like SQL) because I had never done it without also calling ```summarize```. This is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Date := as.IDate(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
           ][, monthly.running.sum :=  cumsum(score),format(Date, "%Y-%m")][]
#          Date score monthly.running.sum
# 1: 2019-10-02     7                   7
# 2: 2019-10-09     6                  13
# 3: 2019-10-16    12                  25
# 4: 2019-10-23     2                  27
# 5: 2019-10-30    13                  40
# 6: 2019-11-06     2                   2
# 7: 2019-11-13     4                   6
# 8: 2019-11-20    15                  21
# 9: 2019-11-27    16                  37
#10: 2019-12-04     4                   4
#11: 2019-12-11    24                  28
#12: 2019-12-18    28                  56
#13: 2019-12-25     8                  64
#14: 2020-01-01     1                   1
#15: 2020-01-08    15                  16
#16: 2020-01-15     9                  25
#17: 2020-01-22     8                  33
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("10/2/2019", "10/9/2019", "10/16/2019", 
"10/23/2019", "10/30/2019", "11/6/2019", "11/13/2019", "11/20/2019", 
"11/27/2019", "12/4/2019", "12/11/2019", "12/18/2019", "12/25/2019", 
"1/1/2020", "1/8/2020", "1/15/2020", "1/22/2020"), score = c(7L, 
6L, 12L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 4L, 15L, 16L, 4L, 24L, 28L, 8L, 1L, 15L, 
9L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R alternative :

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
df$monthly.running.sum <- with(df, ave(score, format(Date, "%Y-%m"),FUN = cumsum))
df

#         Date score monthly.running.sum
#1  2019-10-02     7                   7
#2  2019-10-09     6                  13
#3  2019-10-16    12                  25
#4  2019-10-23     2                  27
#5  2019-10-30    13                  40
#6  2019-11-06     2                   2
#7  2019-11-13     4                   6
#8  2019-11-20    15                  21
#9  2019-11-27    16                  37
#10 2019-12-04     4                   4
#11 2019-12-11    24                  28
#12 2019-12-18    28                  56
#13 2019-12-25     8                  64
#14 2020-01-01     1                   1
#15 2020-01-08    15                  16
#16 2020-01-15     9                  25
#17 2020-01-22     8                  33
```

Answer (score 2):

The yearmon class represents year/month objects so just convert the dates to yearmon and accumulate by them using this one-liner:

```
library(zoo)

transform(DF, run.sum = ave(score, as.yearmon(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"), FUN = cumsum))
```

giving:

```
         Date score run.sum
1   10/2/2019     7       7
2   10/9/2019     6      13
3  10/16/2019    12      25
4  10/23/2019     2      27
5  10/30/2019    13      40
6   11/6/2019     2       2
7  11/13/2019     4       6
8  11/20/2019    15      21
9  11/27/2019    16      37
10  12/4/2019     4       4
11 12/11/2019    24      28
12 12/18/2019    28      56
13 12/25/2019     8      64
14   1/1/2020     1       1
15   1/8/2020    15      16
16  1/15/2020     9      25
17  1/22/2020     8      33
```